# SQL Cast Sub Select to a bit

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

The scenario: I have Projects and Sales Orders. A project can have many Sales Orders. A project can have Multiple "Active" Sales Orders as well. So there are 3 tables:

- Projects
- SalesOrders: has foreign key to the project table
- ActiveSalesOrders: Has an ID, ProjectID, and SalesOrderID

I want a select statement that returns many sales orders. I want to create a calculated column that is true or false. This column basically is *"Does the ActiveSalesOrder table contain my ID"*.

So I am using w3schools database to test since my current database doesn't have data yet. So the conversion is:

- Projects = Orders
- SalesOrders = Products
- ActiveSalesOrders = OrderDetails

Here is the link to run sql commands to their database: [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_op_in)

Here is the sql I ran. It works!!

```
SELECT pr.ProductID,
       pr.ProductName,
       pr.Price,
       CAST(CASE WHEN Price > 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT) AS IsAbove20,
       CAST(
           EXISTS(
               SELECT od.ProductID
               FROM   [OrderDetails] od
               WHERE  od.ProductID = pr.ProductID
           ) AS BIT
       )           AS HasOrderDetails
FROM   [Products]     pr
```

But when I run it in SQL Management it complains the casting with the `as`:
(note: this is converted back to my data model, not the data model of w3schools)

[image]

> Error Message: "Incorrect syntax near 'as'. Expecting ',',AND, or OR."

Not sure where to go from here. I've spent a great deal of time just trying to create the "Cast" statement and was so happy it worked on w3school's engine, but not SQL Server. Any thoughts or links of where I can find the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't have a boolean type.  You need to use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT pr.ProductID,
       pr.ProductName,
       pr.Price,
       CAST(CASE WHEN Price > 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT) AS IsAbove20,
       CAST(CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT od.ProductID
                              FROM OrderDetails od
                              WHERE od.ProductID = pr.ProductID
                             )
                 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
            END AS BIT) AS HasOrderDetails
FROM Products pr;
```

There is really no reason to select columns as bits.  A 0/1 number is fine.  The `bit` data type is not a real boolean in SQL Server, so it just incurs extra overhead for masking operations.

Comment: I keep treating "Bit" as a boolean and there lies my first problem. I didn't think of using a "Case" function. So basically what I understand from your last sentence, there is no reason to "Cast" the "Case" Function since I'm returning either a 1 or 0, correct?

Comment: @jediderek . . . No reason at all.

Comment: Gotcha, I appreciate the lesson you taught me on "Bits".

Answer (score 0):

As @Gordon Linoff taught me, it would be best not to cast a column to a "Bit" like I was doing since it would add overhead. So my answer removes the Casting to show best practice. Thanks!

```
SELECT pr.ProductID,
       pr.ProductName,
       pr.Price,
       CASE 
            WHEN EXISTS(
                     SELECT od.ProductID
                     FROM   [OrderDetails] od
                     WHERE  od.ProductID = pr.ProductID
                 ) THEN 1
            ELSE 0
       END         AS HasOrderDetails
FROM   [Products]     pr;
```